# LVM2 : How to list physical partition identifiers with the UUID of the VG they are assigned to -- or trace one to the other

Tags: lvm

(Rocky Linux 4.18.0-305.25.1.el8_4.x86_64 )

I have 2 Volume Groups.
Both VGs are named "rl", so I need to rename one of them and must use the correct VG UUID to do this.

I cannot find a way to identify which UUID belongs to which VG, as defined by its physical storage.

I have 2 drives.

Each drive has a LUKS volume which contains an LVM2 VG which then contains 3 LVs:

```
sda                                            
├─sda1                                        
└─sda2                                         
  └─luks-bdf533b2-afca-4eda-8029-e0346ebaea99 
    ├─rl-root                                 
    ├─rl-swap                                
    └─rl-home                                
sdc                                            
├─sdc1                                         
└─sdc2                                    
  └─luks-b41a89f1-9040-48df-a10e-11261f899d0f 
    (not active)
```

`pvdisplay` gives me:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/luks-b41a89f1-9040-48df-a10e-11261f899d0f
  VG Name               rl
  ...
  PV UUID               akQG9K-H5x4-U0K1-ij7c-4JQw-rbvk-9NUND5
  
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/luks-bdf533b2-afca-4eda-8029-e0346ebaea99
  VG Name               rl
  ...
  PV UUID               gwKY6m-aesa-XKZZ-TL0d-XdFt-v09N-fRHPI6
```

`vgdisplay` gives me:

```
--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rl        
  ...
  VG UUID               lfTJTT-hCgr-nIfI-VB8o-i0ze-20F3-ReXssf
  
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rl
  ... 
  VG UUID               c70c76-sSDO-EjZd-Zfuc-w3Hw-Da3Y-GM9lf6
```

Obviously, from the above, I cannot tell which VG UUID corresponds to which drive. I cannot find any way to show which physical volumes are attached to which VG because they are both named "rl" and all the output gives name and the only place I can see UUID is in `vgdisplay`.

What I need is to be able to see physical partition identifiers with the UUID of the VG they are assigned to. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know I can list only active vgs or identify by storage size, but I want to know how to do this in a general case. An example would be where I have more than one inactive vg on identical storage media, all with the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it with `vgs` and customized column output:

```
vgs -o vg_name,vg_uuid,pv_uuid
```

It should look somewhat like this:

```
  VG  VG UUID                                PV UUID                               
  rl  lfTJTT-hCgr-nIfI-VB8o-i0ze-20F3-ReXssf akQG9K-H5x4-U0K1-ij7c-4JQw-rbvk-9NUND5
  rl  c70c76-sSDO-EjZd-Zfuc-w3Hw-Da3Y-GM9lf6 gwKY6m-aesa-XKZZ-TL0d-XdFt-v09N-fRHPI6
```

(or the other way around)

Another approach would be to check LVM metadata backups in `/etc/lvm/` (if present).

```
$ grep -r lfTJTT-hCgr /etc/lvm
/etc/lvm/backup/rl: id = "lfTJTT-hCgr-nIfI-VB8o-i0ze-20F3-ReXssf"
```

(and so on for the other UUIDs, then see which files match up)

Or to grab all UUIDs (PV, VG, LV) from a backup file:

```
$ grep 'id = "' /etc/lvm/backup/rl
 id = "lfTJTT-hCgr-nIfI-VB8o-i0ze-20F3-ReXssf"
            id = "gwKY6m-aesa-XKZZ-TL0d-XdFt-v09N-fRHPI6"
```

The grep approach may be interesting if the LVM toolset is not available or if you have the backup stored on another machine, otherwise using the LVM utilities is preferable.

If you merge VGs or move PVs around, there's also a chance the LVM backup files reflect an outdated state of things.

Comment: Cheers! much appreciated. I spent 2hrs googling and trying various options before posting. Your first line lets me match
VG UUID -> PV UUID --(then via pvdisplay)--> PV NAME(LUKS device) --(then via lsblk)--> /dev/sdX.
Maybe someone'll add "show uuid" as an option to pvdisplay at some point.